# Access a namespace/class direct or through another namespace/class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am wondering which below alternative coding is best, both in performance as well as in best practice. Should I import and access classes individually for each namespace/class or do it through a helper namespace/class.

Alt.1  (individual access)

From both a "ProcessRequest" event in a WebHandler and from a "Page_Load" event in a WebForm, there is a need to use JSON and Crypt, so normally one import these 2 namespaces and make calls to its classes individually.

Now, in my example, I also need a combination, where a part of JSON need a Crypt method. In this case a lot more code needs to be made and maintained, in both "ProcessRequest" and "WebForm". This creates a lot more coding so I was thinking, how about do as in "Alt.2" below, access these 2 namespaces through a "Helper" namespace instead?

Alt.2  (through helper access)

In "ProcessRequest" and "WebForm" I make an import to a "Helper" namespace. Then the "Helper" imports both JSON and Crypt and have classes/methods with combined JSON/Crypt calls. This gives me maintenance in one place instead together with less coding.

It would also be simple to expose individual JSON/Crypt methods through the "Helper" class, so now I am thinking, would this alternative be a good way to do it, both in a performance and a best practice way?

If not, what other alternative are there?

Of course there will be some extra work adding classes but on the other hand, if/when some of them change in a way they are called, I have one place to update instead of everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the second approach is better: [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You may also want to read about [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).